# How can I allow a user to execute 'sudo bash' in Unix?

Tags: bash, unix, ubuntu, sudo

I´ve got a nomral user called "Teacher" in my Ubuntu system and it has to be able to execute a "sudo bash" command? How can I achieve this?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that it is a good idea, but if you want, you can simply add such line to `/etc/sudoers` (using `visudo`):

```
Teacher    ALL=(ALL) /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the user to the sudoers list with the `visudo` command (you'll need root privileges to do this). Specify the user you want to grant `sudo` in this format (`user ALL=(ALL) ALL`), so

```
Teacher ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

[How to add a user to the sudoers list](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/how-to-add-a-user-to-the-sudoers-list/) and [How to add users to /etc/sudoers](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/01/06/how-to-add-users-to-etcsudoers/) give step-by-step instructions.

For more information see the [Visudo Manual](http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/visudo.man.html)

Comment: It would be quite dangerous to do this. Might as well just give `Teacher` your root password.

Comment: @Sorpigal I agree ..  but I suppose OP has their reasons. I may add a cautionary note though.